# Recursive function variable problems

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse, postfix-notation

My recursive function accepts a `String prefix` and an `int index`  of this string (0 initially).
Depending on the index calculates a `postfix` string.

`Storage` is a class that holds the `postfix` string and the integer `index` of the prefix string being processed. The purpose of this class is that I can return both string and int.

Another example of input out:
| ^+-ABC+D-EF | AB-C+DEF-+^  |AB-A+AB-^ |

### Examples

| given input | desired output | current output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -+ABC | AB+C- | AB+A- |
| -A+BC | ABC+- | ABC+- |

### Issue

For example `-+ABC` I will result in `AB+A-` instead of expected `AB+C-`, since the index is pointing to 2 instead of 4 at the end.

It works well except the index goes from the correct value of 3 to 1 after I call the return at the bottom.

```
}
```

Any thoughts on best way to correct this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `isOperand` be called `isOperator`?

Comment: Can you post an example of the input, the desired output and the usage of the result ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Example input: -+ABC, -A+BC and desired output: AB+C-, ABC+- and current output: AB+A-, ABC+-

Comment: @k314159 I don't think so.  if its an operand it gets returned (base case), if operator, need to recursively get next two operands which could be complex operands

Comment: It would help, if you can describe the algorithm of `convert` function in "human" language. Furthermore be specific: What does `isOperand(char)` .. return `true` only if `-` or `+` otherwise `false` ?

Comment: @hc_dev hi yes, convert will accept prefix string paramater and the index 0 to start.  It then stored ch as the first character, and if that character isOperand (A,B,C....) it will return that character and the index (base case).    Else, two recursive calls to convert with increasing the index by 1 before each.  Finally, it returns the postfix and current index.  Postfix1 and postfix2 are "Storage" objects which hold the string and index.  Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: I previously misunderstood - now I understand `isOperand(char)` is true only if char is, for example "A" or "B". This is a method to convert to "Reverse Polish Notation", right? If so, add the tag [postfix-notation] - it will help people understand and also bring in postfix-notation experts.

Comment: @k314159 thank, yes you're correct.  I will add the tag

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the index but not using it. Thus, when `convert` processes a non-trivial expression, it advances the index by more than 1 and returns it, but you discard that returned value and advance it by 1. You can fix this by making use of the index.

Replace the second occurrence of

```
        index += 1;
```

with

```
        index = postfix1.getIndex() + 1;
```